# How to mock a django settings config value inside __init__

Tags: django, mocking, pytest

I have this scenario:

```
class MyClass:
    my_protocol: MyProtocol

    def __init__(self) -> None:        
        if settings.EXAMPLE == "foo":
            self.my_protocol = Foo()
        elif settings.EXAMPLE == "bar":
            self.my_protocol = Bar()
            
    def my_method(self) -> Union[int, None]:
        [...]
        result = self.my_protocol.another_method()
        [...]
```

I'm using a variable inside settings.py to choice which method to use. It's ok, my code works.

But I need to write some tests.

Something like this:

```
@override_settings(EXAMPLE="foo")
def test_my_procotol():
    ...
```

The value changed works only inside method (my_method). Inside the `__init__` the value not changes.

Does anyone have any ideas?